# Deploying ebextensions on Elastic beanstalk and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war, ebextensions

recently i am having a timeout issue while using my application deployed to Elastic Beanstalk and EC2. Initially, the error was 504 after 60 seconds, and upon reading some forums/discussions, i changed the EC2 load balancer idle time to 600 seconds. When i try again, it became error 502 after 60 seconds (another timeout). Thus, i believe this timeout is from the application itself, and i tried to include ebextension file into the project directory.

I am packaging the project as a war and upload it to the aws tomcat server.
My war file structure is as follows:

```
.ebextensions
app
META-INF
WEB-INF
```

Am i doing anything wrong in term of the .ebextensions location? It seems like it is not reading the config file, or perhaps the config file could not solve my timeout issue?

The content of the config file within .ebextensions are:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
option_name: Timeout
value: 1800
```

Hope anyone of you can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Upon searching the web for the answer, I finally come across a blog which exactly portrays my problems and showing the step by step on how to solve the issues. For those who are facing the similar problem, you can check out this link.

https://blog.tier1app.com/2017/03/09/detective-story-troubleshooting-timeout-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk/